# Postfix - status=bounced (unknown user "myuser")

Tags: postfix-mta

I am configuring Postfix and when validating by telnet and SMTP I got the status bounced error, unknown user:

**Error log**:

> postfix/local[18718]: 4590D7DC0A51: to=myuser@mydomain.example, relay=local, delay=9.8, delays=9.8/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "myuser")

The "myuser" already exists, but with full domain name: `myuser@mydomain.example`.

**User Validation**:

```
 postmap -q myuser@mydomain.example mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
```

Output is: "1" - so I guess it is OK.

**My postfix Configuration**:

```
root# postconf -n:
append_at_myorigin = yes
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
delay_warning_time = 8h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = yes
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maximal_queue_lifetime = 6d
mydestination = mydomain.example
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_delay_reject = no
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 10
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain,             reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 5
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

you have added  `mydestination = mydomain.example` and so the valid users for `mydomain.example` will be searched in `local_recipient_maps`. It is very clear from the logline that `local` delivery agent is selected to deliver the mail, as local domain class matched. See [postfix address classes](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) for more help

Modify your main.cf like below

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
mydestination =
# set to localhost localhost.$mydomain or remove mydomain.example for now
# Ensure that postmap -q mydomain.example mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf is returning mydomain.example and
# postmap -q myuser@mydomain.example mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf succeeds
```

Comment: I was configuring use of AWS SES with SMTP and was noticing local delivery. This fixes my issue. It's so weird its not mentioned in the AWS docs (maybe I just didn't find it...). Thanks!

Comment: I don't have /etc/postfix/mysql-* files, but changing mydestination worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Open `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, look for the `mydestination` field and change it's value to the below

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

Don't forget to run `sudo postfix reload` afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Use following settings in `/var/postfix/main.cf`

```
myorigin = localhost
myhostname = <your_host_name>
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

followed by:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
sudo service postfix restart
```

Comment: This worked for me, except the `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`, that returned `postmap: fatal: open /etc/postfix/virtual: No such file or directory` – Still OK for me

Answer (score 0):

For someone else, when I set `mydestination=mydomain.example`.
Postfix show warning do not list domain `mydomain.example` in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains. So I set it `relayhost = mydomain.example`

My postfix version: 3.1.0 (`postconf -d | grep mail_version`)